ApolloError: Variable "$sku_id" of required type "Int!" was not provided
Here's a more refined version of your problem formatted for Stack Overflow:

Problem with Apollo Client: "Variable $sku_id of required type Int! was not provided."
I'm working on a task where I need to use React Class Components with Apollo Client to fetch product details using a GraphQL query from the backend. The backend is built using PHP and GraphQL.
Problem:
I have a ProductDetails component that fetches a product by its sku_id (which is extracted from the URL) and passes it as a query variable. However, I'm encountering the following error:
ApolloError: Variable "$sku_id" of required type "Int!" was not provided.

Observations:

In the network tab, the request payload shows that the variable is being passed correctly:
{
  "operationName": "getProductDetails",
  "variables": { "sku_id": 1 },
  "query": "query getProductDetails($sku_id: Int!) { ... }"
}


But the response contains the following error:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$sku_id\" of required type \"Int!\" was not provided.",
      "locations": [{ "line": 1, "column": 25 }]
    }
  ]
}



Code snippets:
GraphQL Root Query (PHP):
<?php
use App\Models\Product;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ObjectType;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;

$rootQuery = new ObjectType([
    "name" => "query",
    "fields" => [
        "product" => [
            "type" => $productType,
            "args" => [
                "sku_id" => Type::int(),
            ],
            "resolve" => function ($root, $args) {
                if (!is_int($args["sku_id"])) {
                    throw new \GraphQL\Error\Error('Invalid sku_id provided. sku_id must be an integer.');
                }

                return Product::with(['attributes', 'galleries', 'prices'])
                    ->where("sku_id", $args["sku_id"])
                    ->first();
            },
        ],
    ],
]);

React Class Component (ProductDetails):
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Query } from '@apollo/client/react/components';
import { GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS } from '../../graphql/queries.js';

class ProductDetails extends Component {
    render() {
        const param = Number(window.location.pathname.split("/")[2] || null);
        const sku_id = parseInt(param, 10); // Extract the ID from the URL

        return (
            <Query query={GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS} variables={{ sku_id }}>
                {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                    if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>;

                    if (error) {
                        console.error("Error details:", error);
                        return <p>Error occurred</p>;
                    }

                    const { product } = data;
                    return (
                        <div>
                            {product ? <h1>{product.name}</h1> : <p>Product not found</p>}
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            </Query>
        );
    }
}

export default ProductDetails;

What I've tried:

Ensured the sku_id is being passed as an integer.
Checked that the GraphQL schema expects an Int! for sku_id.
Confirmed that the backend query works correctly when tested directly in a GraphQL client.

Question:
Why am I getting the error Variable "$sku_id" of required type "Int!" was not provided. even though the payload shows the correct variable being passed?

This reformatted post is now ready for submission to Stack Overflow!
